# Segmentation fault while trying to print contents of char*

Tags: c

I have the following piece of code:

```
    FILE *fpa;
    fpa = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (fpa == NULL) {
     printf("Error: could not open seqA file!\n");
     exit(0);
    }

    unsigned int N_a;
    fscanf(fpa, "%d\n", &N_a);
    char *seq_a = malloc((N_a+1) * sizeof(char *));
    strcpy(seq_a,"");
    fscanf(fpa, "%s\n", seq_a);
    fclose(fpa);

    for(i=0;i<N_a;i++)
      printf("%s", seq_a[i]); ---> SEG FAULT
    printf("\n");
```

I am getting a segmentation fault at the printf statement.
argv[2] is a file whose contents is:
           5
           ABCBB

Any idea where i might be making a mistake.

Comment: `char *seq_a = malloc((N_a+1) * sizeof(char *));` should have `sizeof(char)` instead of the pointer, although that shouldn't segfault.

Comment: I don't know that it would cause a seg fault, but `printf("%s", seq_a[i]);` is trying to print a string, but seq_a[i] is a char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char *seq_a = malloc((N_a+1) * sizeof(char *));

should be:     `char *seq_a = malloc((N_a+1) * sizeof(char));`

If you want to print each char then use `%c`:

```
  printf("%c", seq_a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are printing *characters*, your `printf` should use format specifier `%c`.. not `%s`. `%s` expects a pointer, so it's treating a character value as a location in memory.